# How styling ActionBarTab indicator programmatically?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar-compat

I'm use ActionBar compact in my app and created 2 Tab and Spinner Menu Item. Now I want make change tab indicator by selected item spinner, like this picture :
[image]
but i don't know how make it. I just styling in theme with code :

part of **Style.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.MyAB" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>

    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
    </style>
```

and this part of **MyActivity.class** where Tab is created

```
@Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate our menu from the resources by using the menu inflater.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);   ;

        MenuItem actionbar_form= menu.findItem(Menus.FORM);

        View view1= (View) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(actionbar_form);
        if (view1 instanceof Spinner)
        {
            final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view1;
           spinner.setAdapter(adapterSpinnerMenuForm);


            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //  TextView txtType= (TextView)spinner.getAdapter().getView(position, null, null).findViewById(R.id.txtType);
                    Variabel.type= adapterSpinnerMenuForm.spinnerNavItem.get(position).getType();

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });


        }
        return true;
}
```

so how the change indicator tab Actionbar with programatically ? sorry for my english

Comment: Note that action bar tabs are deprecated in Android 5.0.

Comment: but i still want use it in older android 5.0

Comment: You can use one method for all versions via the Sliding tabs. There is an official sample of it here: http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html. There is also a good library for it here: https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this [ActionBar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100)